# Custom BigInteger add(3,2) returns {5,0}

Tags: biginteger

im trying to do a custom BigInteger class with .add method.
This is my code:

```
public BigNumber plus(BigNumber other) {
        int[] resultPointer = new int[Math.max(digits.length, other.digits.length) + 1];
        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < resultPointer.length - 1; i++) {
            int left = digits.length > i ? digits[i] : 0;
            int right = other.digits.length > i ? other.digits[i] : 0;

            int result = left + right + carry;
            carry = result >= 10 ? result - 9 : 0;
            resultPointer[i] = result <= 9 ? result : 9;
        }

        return new BigNumber(resultPointer);
    }
```

and result its BigNumber (My biginteger name class of 50, concretly int{5,0})

Comment: Why resultPointer[i] = result <= 9 ? result : 9; ? Shouldn't it be result-10 instead of 9? And shouldn't carry be 1 instead of result -9? And probably many other bugs, it is bit hard to follow what is happening here.

Comment: You are rigth, i will try other implementation